# Get the number of orders with status 'completed' AND 'processing'

Tags: php, api, magento, mage

I use a Magento market segmentation plugin and I am trying to segment not only the users that have order status "completed" but "completed" AND "processing".

The original code part for segmenting based on customers looks as follows:

```
if ($this->getAttribute() == 'ordered') {
        $customersOrders = Mage::helper('marketsuite/customer')->getOrderCollectionByCustomerIds($_customerIds);
        $customersOrders->addFieldToFilter('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
        $_arrayOrderIdCustomerId = $customersOrders->getConnection()->fetchPairs($customersOrders->getSelect());
        $_arrayOrderIdTotal = $this->_getValidatedTotalOrderedCount(array_keys($_arrayOrderIdCustomerId));
        $_validatedArrayOrderIdCustomerId = array_intersect_key($_arrayOrderIdCustomerId, $_arrayOrderIdTotal);
```

Another part for segmentating based on orders:

```
public function validateOrderCollection(Zend_Db_Select $select)
{
    if ($this->getAttribute() == 'ordered') {
        $select
            ->where('state = ?', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE)
        ;
        $_orderIds = Mage::helper('marketsuite/order')->getAllIds($select);
        $orderTotals = $this->_getValidatedTotalOrderedCount($_orderIds);
        $validatedOrders = array();
        foreach ($orderTotals as $orderId => $totalOrderedCount) {
            if ($this->validateAttribute($totalOrderedCount)) {
                array_push($validatedOrders, $orderId);
            }
        }
        return $validatedOrders;
    }
    return array();
}
```

Question: How do I include both "completed" and "processing" orders in both cases. I know it has something to do with this part `$customersOrders->addFieldToFilter('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);` but I am not exactly sure how to achieve this.

Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach:

```
$connection = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = 'SELECT `customer_id` FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE `status` LIKE ? OR `status` LIKE ?';
$customers = $connection->fetchAll($sql, array('complete', 'processing'));
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
foreach ($customers as $customer_info){
    $customer = $customer->load($customer_info['customer_id']);
    /* Do what you need to do here, e.g:
     * echo $customer->getName() . "<br/>";
     * This example will print all customers who have complete/processing orders full names
     */
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but actually I'm not really sure where to put it in my example posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$customersOrders->addFieldToFilter('state', 
          array(
                    array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE),
                    array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING),
                )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately that did not help. I'm using Market Segmentation Suite by aheadWorks. The only hint I got is to have a look at in a specific file starting with this two lines =/